# MySQL - How To query a table result that involves preceding calculated values

Tags: mysql, sql

Say i have a table `items` sorted ascending by `date`

| date | item | quantity | cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | Pencil | 12 | 10.00 |
| 2022-12-02 | Pencil | 10 | 10.00 |
| 2022-12-04 | Pencil | 5 | 10.00 |
| 2022-12-06 | Eraser | 10 | 4.00 |
| 2022-12-10 | Eraser | 50 | 4.00 |
| 2022-12-15 | Eraser | 25 | 4.00 |

I need to write an SQL query that returns a calculated field called `calculated_cost`, where the expression is simply `quantity` * `cost`

Then I will need to increment `calculated_cost` for every row and save it to a field called `accumulated_cost`

However here is the challenge, I am also required to store a field called `previous_accumulated_cost` where it takes the preceding `accumulated_cost` and store it as a value.

Note that I also need to calculate these by partitioning based on `item` and order by `date`, means i need to reset the `accumulated_cost` and `previous_accumulated_cost` when I reach a new item.

Basically i need to generate an output like this.

| date | item | quantity | cost | calculated_cost | accumulated_cost | previous_accumulated_cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-01 | Pencil | 12 | 10.00 | 120.00 | 120.00 | 0.00 |
| 2022-12-02 | Pencil | 10 | 10.00 | 100.00 | 220.00 | 120.00 |
| 2022-12-04 | Pencil | 5 | 10.00 | 50.00 | 270.00 | 220.00 |
| 2022-12-06 | Eraser | 10 | 4.00 | 40.00 | 40.00 | 0.00 |
| 2022-12-10 | Eraser | 50 | 4.00 | 200.00 | 240.00 | 40.00 |
| 2022-12-15 | Eraser | 25 | 4.00 | 100.00 | 340.00 | 240.00 |

I have already tried an SQL query like this

```
SELECT *,
   (i.quantity * i.cost) AS calculated_cost,
   SUM(i.quantity * i.cost) OVER (PARTITION BY i.item ORDER BY i.date) AS accumulated_cost,
   IFNULL(LAG(i2.accumulated_cost) OVER (PARTITION BY i.item ORDER BY i.date), 0) AS previous_accumulated_cost
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT item, SUM(quantity * cost) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS accumulated_cost
   FROM items 
) i2 ON i.item = i2.item
```

However this doesn't work, as the number of item entries can keep increasing and I am not sure how to keep referencing back the `previous_accumulated_cost`

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hunch to use analytic functions was spot on.  I would suggest using this version:

```sql
SELECT
    quantity * cost AS calculated_cost,
    SUM(quantity * cost) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) AS accumulated_cost,
    SUM(quantity * cost) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY date) - (quantity * cost) AS previous_accumulated_cost
FROM items
ORDER BY item, date;
```

Appreciate that the `previous_accumulated_cost` is simply the `accumulated_cost` minus the `calculated_cost`.

Comment: Thanks this seems much simpler and straightforward for the issue!